# Math history research: a copy of "Zur relativen Wertbemessung der Turnierresultate" , eigenvector centrality by Edmund Landau

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, ho.history-overview, paper-request

I'm searching for a copy of an old paper made by Edmund Landau:

> *Zur relativen Wertbemessung der Turnierresultate*, Deutsches Wochenschach, 11. Jahrgang (1895), 366–369.

However, I can't find it anywhere. I looked at some old books written by Landau and did not succeed in my quest.

The Princeton University has the volume 50-1895 of the magazine *"Deutsche Schachzeitung"* where this paper should appear: [HathiTrust record](https://catalog.hathitrust.org/Record/009008387).

Landau published this early work in a Chess magazine. However, it seems to be that paper has several implications in the theory of Ranking and positive matrices and worked as a motivation for the next works of Landau.

Comment: Perhaps you can find help from a librarian. Tracking down old materials is part of their expertise.

Comment: I'm thinking about that. Perhaps some big and old library has the book where this article was published. However, I don't know how can I achieve that. I'm just a student in Brazil.

Comment: For example, the Princeton University seems to have the specific volume where this paper appears, v50-1895  https://catalog.hathitrust.org/Record/009008387

Comment: Right, but I think your university librarians might have a way to help. Libraries are often part of international networks which allow them to share books with each other. One such network is WorldCat https://www.worldcat.org/ You can try going through them yourself, but in any case, remember that librarians have masters or PhD's in Library Science, so they really know a lot.

Comment: You probably know this already, but E. Landau seems to have written more about the topic in "Zeitschrift für Mathematik und Physik“ , vol. 63, pages 192-208. That is one famous issue because of a certain A. Einstein a few pages later.

Comment: Neither MathSciNet nor zbMath know of a paper from 1895 by Landau. But then it's a Chess magazine, so I'm not sure why you are asking here... Google books gives these snippets for 1895: https://books.google.com.au/books?redir_esc=y&id=kykCAAAAYAAJ&pg=PR1&sig=ACfU3U3pck7_uWtkOhTm0BWSVdZsxSrn7g&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=landau

Comment: And here's the WorldCat page for the periodical: https://www.worldcat.org/title/deutsches-wochenschach-und-berliner-schachzeitung/oclc/50283180 (maybe the title changed at some point, it's not clear). Unfortunately the Internet Archive only has the years 1889 and 1890

Comment: If you manage to get a copy, it's out of copyright, so I recommend hosting a scan in a stable location, or, even better, since it's not that long, transcribe it to LaTeX if you at all can, and host it on the arXiv.

Comment: I already tried the google book. As can been seen the scan of google book is incomplete.  In archve.org there are some  volumes of this magazine, but the specific year or 1895 is missing  https://archive.org/search.php?query=Deutsches%20Wochenschach.

Comment: Ok, the paper was published in a chess magazine. However,  "Zur relativen Wert Messung der Turnierresultate" is referenced in several works about ranking problem and graph theory.

Comment: You could also try to ask at chess.stackexchange.com ,

Comment: Thanks for the sugestion @DagOskarMadsen! It's a realy good idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The paper which actually was Landau's first scientific paper written at the tender age of 18, was published in his Collected Works, vol. 1. In it, he proposes to rank chess players having played a round robin tournament according to an eigenvector of the results matrix . A much more comprehensive analysis of this method with the help of the (then new) Perron-Frobenius theorem is given in his 1915 paper "Über Preisverteilung bei Spielturnieren", to be found in his Collected Works, vol. 6.
The latter paper can be downloaded here: https://iris.univ-lille.fr/handle/1908/2031

Comment: It seems very hard to get a copy from this Collected Works . But I'm  happy now with this 1915 paper. Thanks.

It's sad, those papers deserves an english translation.

Comment: The introduction of his 1915 paper is a restatement of his earlier paper, i.e. the proposal to rate the players according to an eigenvector of the results matrix, which in chess contains the values 1, 1/2 and 0. In §1 he says that all is well if the results matrix is irreducible. §2 shows the possibility of a nonunique rating if the matrix is reducible. In §3 he shows that in certain cases inconsistencies can occur, namely that the score of a player can decrease if the outcome of a certain match is changed in his or her favor, which ultimately leads him to reject his own method.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an account in springer you can see here:

https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-1-4615-4819-5_23

Comment: It's a great compendium about some works of E. Landau. However, "Zur relativen Wertbemessung der Turnierresultate" was not published in this  chapter